# Recurrence Relation and closed form representation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Consider the following recurrence relation describing a function $F$ whose domain is the set of all nonnegative integers:

$$F(0) = 2$$

$$F(N) = 3F(N-1) + 5; \quad N > 0$$

Question:  How to give a closed-form representation for $F$?

Comment: the answer I was told was (3^(n+2) -5)/2

Comment: that is the closed form representation but I am unsure how that is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Try to expand:
$$F(n) = 3(3F(n-2) + 5) + 5 = 3^2 F(n-2) + 3\times 5  + 5 = 3^2(3F(n-3) + 5) + 3\times 5 + 5 = 3^3 F(n-3) + 3^2\times 5 + 3\times 5 + 5 = \cdots = 3^{n}F(0) + (\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 3^i) \times 5 = 2\times 3^n + 5 \times \frac{3^n - 1}{2} = (2 + \frac{5}{2})\times 3^n - \frac{5}{2} = \frac{9}{2}\times 3^n-\frac{5}{2} = \frac{9\times 3^n - 5}{2} = \frac{3^{n+2} - 5}{2}$$

Comment: how did you get 9 in the last line? 9 x 3^n -5

Comment: @yoobi Try to sum $2 + \frac{5}{2} = \frac{9}{2}$.

Comment: sorry can you show all your work in that last step. I dont see where the 9 came from.

Comment: everything else is clear

Comment: @yoobi see the updated solution.

Comment: nice thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**
$$f_1=3f_0+5$$
$$f_2=3^2f_0+3\cdot 5+5$$
$$f_3=3^3f_0+3^2\cdot 5+3\cdot 5+5$$
$$f_4=3^4f_0+3^3\cdot 5+3^2\cdot 5+3\cdot 5+5$$
$$...$$
$$f_n=3^n f_0+3^{n-1}\cdot 5+3^{n-2}\cdot 5+...+3\cdot 5+5$$

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding, is there somewhere I can read up more on this?

Comment: @yoobi Try this post: http://nilknarf.langlab.org/entries/2017-1-12.html

Answer (score 0):

Hint: divide $\,f_n = 3f_{n-1} +5\,$ by $\,3^n\,$, then telescope:

$$\dfrac{f_n}{3^n} = \dfrac{f_{n-1}}{3^{n-1}} + 5 \cdot \dfrac{1}{3^n}=\dfrac{f_{n-2}}{3^{n-2}} +5 \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{3^{n-1}} +\dfrac{1}{3^n}\right)=\ldots=\dfrac{f_0}{3^0}+ 5 \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{3}+ \ldots\dfrac{1}{3^{n-1}} +\dfrac{1}{3^n}\right)$$